# How to create a javascript object with the same attributes as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Ni55aN/D3-Node-Editor) in my angular 2 application.

The thing is that I want to create the menu dynamically, but I need to use a javascript object. How can I convert an array into the expected object?

Imagine that I have this array:

```
var arr = ["element1", "element2"];
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
{
   element1: myFunction,
   element2: myFunction
}
```

(myFunction is a function that it's defined in the scope)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with JSON at all..

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's just a javascript object. I've already edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this

```
arr.reduce((accumulator, value) => { 
  accumulator[value] = myFunction; 
  return accumulator;
}, {})
```

Basically what's happening, is that you are using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) function to do the same thing as what's happening in the solution with the for-loop.

Comment: I'd be happy to upvote this answer, but I recommend you explain what's happening here, and formatting code so it isn't all jammed into one line.  The person asking the question is clearly new to JavaScript.

Comment: or just `arr.reduce((accumulator, value) => ({...accumulator, [[value]]: myFunction}), {})`

Answer (score 3):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function on array and create key value pair.

```js
var arr = ["element1", "element2"];
var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(item){
    
      obj[item]= function myfunction(){};

});

console.log(obj);
```